# Memory modified at jump far

Tags: windows, x86, x86-64, tracing

Observing a trace of Wow64 switching on Windows 7, the following situation makes me confused

```
...
0x77491dbe  64 ff 15 c0 00 00 00  call fs:[0xc0]          ; syswow64\ntdll.dll
0x74632320  ea 1e 27 63 74 33 00  jmp far 0x33:0x7463271e ; system32\wow64cpu.dll
0x7463271e  67 44 8b 04 24        mov r8d, [esp]          ; system32\wow64cpu.dll
...
```

The first instruction is something similar with [X86SwitchTo64BitMode](http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=102), the second one is a switch back to 64-bit mode. So `wow64cpu.dll` has been actually mapped into two different code segments: `cs = 23` for compat mode (second instruction) and `cs = 33` for 64-bit mode (third instruction).

However I cannot find the second instruction (`jmp far...`) in the corresponding dll. There are `ea 1e 27 b6 78...` at `0x74632320`, not `ea 1e 27 64...` as being observed in the trace.

Was `wow64cpu.dll` modified when being mapped into the memory?